# Property of Cesaro summable 0-1 sequences

Tags: limits, cesaro-summable

Assume that $a_n$, $b_n$ and $c_n$ are 0-1 sequences such that
$$
a=\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n,
\,
c=\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N c_n,
\,
d=\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n c_n,
\,
b=\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N b_n
$$
exist. Suppose also that $a=b$ and $d=ac$. Can I conclude that 
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N b_n c_n =d
$$
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let:

- $a_n=1$ if $n\equiv 0,1$ mod $4$
- $b_n=1$ if $n\equiv 1,3$ mod $4$
- $c_n=1$ if $n\equiv 0,2$ mod $4$

Then $a=c=\tfrac 12$ and $a=b$ and $d=ac,$ but $\sum_{n=1}^Nb_nc_n$ is always zero.